# Meta tags in google

Tags: html, facebook

I'm here with a doubt about how should I use my tags to accomplish the same as Facebook.
If you go on this link https://www.google.com/#q=facebook you'll see that the facebook has many pages by level.

Kind of like this:

```
Welcome to Facebook...

  > LogIn        > Signup
  > OtherPage    > OtherPage
```

I would like to get this results as well on my pages. So imagine that I have three pages (**index.php**, **signup.php** and **login.php**). 
What tags should I use on different pages to get that output on google?

```
<title>Index</title>
<link rel='shortcut icon' href='images/theico.ico' type='image/x-icon'>
<meta name='robots' content='index,follow'>
<meta name='description' content='description testing'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are talking about sitelinks:

From the documentation of google webmaster tools

> Sitelinks Sitelinks are automatically generated links that may appear
>   under your site's search results. Learn more. If you don't want a page
>   to appear as a sitelink, you can demote it. Only site owners and users
>   with full permissions can demote sitelinks.

[More info from google help](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en)